# Cant use ModalManager load modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I follow  [text](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Modals) to code a modal dialog, first i make file /Products/ProductInfoModal.cshtml

```
@page
@model MyProject.Web.Pages.Products.ProductInfoModalModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<abp-modal>
    <abp-modal-header title="Product Information"></abp-modal-header>
    <abp-modal-body>
        <h3>@Model.ProductName</h3>
        <div>
            <img src="@Model.ProductImageUrl" />
        </div>
        <p>
            @Model.ProductDescription
        </p>
        <p>
            <small><i>Reference: https://acme.com/catalog/</i></small>
        </p>
    </abp-modal-body>
    <abp-modal-footer buttons="Close"></abp-modal-footer>
</abp-modal>
```

then i make file /Products/ProductInfoModal.cshtml.cs

```
using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.RazorPages;

namespace MyProject.Web.Pages.Products
{
    public class ProductInfoModalModel : AbpPageModel
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ProductName = "Acme Indestructo Steel Ball";
            ProductDescription = "The ACME Indestructo Steel Ball is completely indestructible, there is nothing that can destroy it!";
            ProductImageUrl = "https://acme.com/catalog/acmeindestructo.jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

then i put these code in index.js under /Pages dir

```
$(function () {
    abp.log.debug('Index.js initialized!');
    var productInfoModal = new abp.ModalManager({
        viewUrl: '/Products/ProductInfoModal'
    });
    productInfoModal.open();
});
```

but when i run the code i got these error:

```
    localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (modal-manager.js?_v=…106460000000:147:91)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:10243:14)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:383:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:205:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:10242:9)
    at fire (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:3223:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:3353:7)
    at done (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:9629:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js?_v=638410704920210000:9888:9)
```

somebody meet same problem?